# How to find out why system terminates app

Tags: android

After running my app some minutes the app is just terminated. The activity `onPause()` is called but then nothing. To me it feels like it is the system that terminates the app. How do I find out the reason for this termination?

I have a custom default exception handler to catch any, otherwise, uncaught exceptions. This is not called so I don't think the termination is from a crash.
And I can also see that the activity `onPause()` is called, but not `onStop()`.
I have looked at the Android Studio Profiler but it doesn't look like the memory or cpu went up prior to the termination.

Comment: Have you looked in LogCat?

Comment: stop answering your own question, instead edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to use debug mode. Use Breakpoints.

Answer (score -1):

Aaa, I just found out that it was a native crash that caused the system to force finishing my activity. It looks like it was because of usage of opengl in a lib that I have included. And I guess that native crashes is not seen by the default exception handler then, since I did not get any hit there.
Thanks Blundell for making me think twice about the LogCat. I had to use the usb to external connections so I could not log over usb. So I had created my own logging to a file on sdcard. This made my app only write my own logs to the sdcard and that's where I could only see the onPause as the last log. When I now instead logged the whole logcat over WIFI to adb I could see the native crash in the log.
The crash was just before the logcat line:
W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myapp/.ActivityGUILayer